# Draw svg file on highchart or inside html tag

Tags: svg, highcharts

How to draw a svg file (or svg document) on hichchart surface or inside a HTML tag?
I want this so I can draw our company `logo.svg` on a chart.
I can draw `logo.png` on a chart with the below code but I do not want to do it like this

```
    chart.renderer.image(
'/Styles/images/icons/Chart Logo.png', 45, chart.plotHeight+15,48,40).add();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could include the svg document [using an object or embed element](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_inhtml.asp) in the larger HTML document.  And then use CSS to place the element on the chart.  [Example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/64x5D/)

[image]

Comment: tanks for your reply, but in mode, when we export chart the circle dose not included, is their a solution for this?

Comment: Hmm, apparently you can add the svg with the chart.renderer.image function (http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/24QPF/1/), but the export still fails though.  Is there anyway you can include your svg directly into the  html on the backend and then add it as a svg group using that renderer option?